# Object == null vs boolean == false

Tags: java, performance, object, if-statement, boolean

I need to assign an object if it's not assigned yet.

```
Object obj;
While(true){
    if(obj == null) obj = new Object();
    //do other things
}
```

or

```
Object obj;
boolean isObjAssigned;
While(true){
    if(!isObjAssigned) obj = new Object();
    //do other things
}
```

Which of these two checking methods is a better practice?

Comment: Both use incorrect syntax and they don't do the same thing.

Comment: is app multithreading? can't you use a singleton pattern?

Comment: @JordiCastilla no it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer the first one:

```
Object obj;
while(true){
    if (obj == null) obj = new Object();
    //do other things
}
```

In the second example, you're coupling the value of the `Boolean` with the `Object` and this approach can also lead to errors, because you can accidentally set the value of the `Boolean` to `true`, without instantiating the `Object`. 
This way you'd assume the `Object` had been instantiated, according to the `Boolean` value, and you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

The best, IMHO, syntax *in the context* is just to pull the assign *out of the loop*:

```
  Object obj = new Object();

  while (true) {
    // do other things
  }
```

In *more elaborated example*, e.g.

```
  Object obj;                    // obj contains trash, not necessary null
  Boolean isObjAssigned = false; // note "= false;"

  if (...) { // obj can be either assigned or not (depending on the condition)
    obj = ...
    isObjAssigned = true; // do not forget this
  }

  while (true) {
    if (!isObjAssigned) {
      obj = new Object();
      isObjAssigned = true; // do not forget this in order not to reassign obj 
    }

    // do other things
  }
```

in *general case* you have to use a `Boolean` *flag*.

Comment: the thing is I don't know when I will receive the object to assign it, it's onLocationChanged - google maps v2

Comment: @user3553447 Then why need check, just assign it when you receive the object and if received object is null, assign your own.

Comment: I want to animate it from the first location to the received one.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not allow you to write in the first way and it complains "Variable might not have been initialized." and  it will force you to put it as null. In that case checking for again same null is redundant. Nevertheless First one is better! since we should use as less variables as possible.

```
Object obj=null;
while(true){
    if(obj == null) obj = new Object();
    //do other things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that some times Object can be assigned with `null` as well from other places.

Hence check for null and assign. That's fine. Go for **first way**.

There is no boolean required at all it seems. But here is the gotach, if you don't want to reassign it use the boolean and lock it (that remembers me the `final` key word ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any performance difference between the two, if you want to reuse the condition `isObjAssigned` further in your method then use the local variable to check, else checking it to `null` in the `if` block should be self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd approach will throw a NullPointerException becauuse you are using the Object version of `boolean` (`java.lang.Boolean`).

Instead use `boolean`.

However, I would suggest the first approach, otherwise there may be a risk of the object assignment and the `isObjAssigned` flag becoming out of sync.